# Path to K2 status

Tags: science-based, technological-development

Im looking to make a small web choice based game. 
The aim harness all the suns power as soon as possible.

High score depends on overall population of solar system and the time it took to get to the point of full coverage.

Setting: Today's technology level + practical fusion, no FTL, extreme life extension is on the cards, all technology as science-based as possible within out current understanding

Question: What would be the right path to get to K2 status? what could be pitfalls along the way? what choice can prevent the solar system development etc..

Comment: Welcome to the site, Avi. Please note that the [tag:science-based] tag should not be the only tag on a question. I have edited your question to correct this. If you disagree with my changes, feel free to roll them back.

Comment: I'm not sure that there is any one "right path". In fact, there are almost certainly _many_ approaches, to the point where this question becomes entirely too broad to be reasonably answered here. Remember that a civilisation could reach K2 without using 100% of the energy from our sun, by using energy in other solar systems, too. The definition doesn't require just one star.

Comment: I suppose i should include population leakage to other start systems as part of the question? maybe right path is a bad way of putting it i want events that would be hurdles to the process

Comment: Too many questions. You are basically asking others to write your game for you. You need a specific single question.   Also, it would be nice to show some effort on your own. Search out some info on Dyson swarms, etc.